# Dynamic Links - Domain and path prefix are being released. Please retry in one month

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Trying to add a new URL Prefix shows me this message, do you know why is this been showing up?

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I have the same issue since couple of days. Contacted firebase support, below is the response.

> When you see the message “Domain and path prefix are being released.
>   Please retry in one month.“, you usually have to wait for a full 30
>   days before you can claim the domain again. I can try to appeal your
>   case to the engineering team. However, I can't guarantee on when this
>   will be available. Just to set an expectation, our engineers usually
>   respond within one to two weeks or depends on their availability. Our
>   last resort is to wait for a month to refresh or use another Dynamic
>   Link domain.
>
> Let me know if you'd like to proceed and confirm the
>   following details:
>
> • Firebase Project ID
>
> • Domain you'd like to use

Looking forward to your response.

Comment: This shows how unwilling and no-where-near-fully-capable firebase really is.

Comment: Two and a half years later, this is still happening.

Comment: Just wanted to pop in and say this is still the case in 2022.

Comment: Disappointing...

Comment: Embarrasing....

Comment: This is too sad.

Comment: Well, FDLs are dead anyway, but in case you were wondering, this is still happening in 2024.